# objdump not found on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, elf, objdump, dwarf

I will like to use the objdump command on cygwin. I get the exception:

> -bash: objdump: command not found

why cygwin is not able to find objdump?

EDIT
---- I am able to see binutils at http://cygwin.com/packages/  . once I find the binutils package I click on it and it takes me to [here](http://cygwin.com/packages/binutils/). How do I install it? what am I supposed to do once I got there?

Comment: Did you install `binutils`? Are the programs from `binutils` in your `PATH`?

Comment: Q: Why cygwin is not able to find objdump? A: because you didn't install it!  Get "binutils" from wherever you got Cygwin :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! How do I know if I installed binutils? I am able to run cygwin and execute linux commans like cd, ls, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the Cygwin [setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe) and use it to install the `binutils` package.